# Pass path of shortcut file to CustomAction

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have a shortcut definition like this:

```
<Component Id="PowershellShortcut" Guid="{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}">
  <Condition>POWERSHELL_INSTALL_LOCATION</Condition>
  <Shortcut Id="PowershellStartMenuShortcut"
            Name="Powershell Environment"
            Description="Powershell Environment"
            Target="[POWERSHELL_INSTALL_LOCATION]"
            Arguments="-PSConsoleFile &quot;[#Powershell.Environment]&quot;" />
</Component>
```

I want to pass the path to the resultant `.lnk` file into a CustomAction. I've tried various things, e.g.:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionData_ElevatePowershellShortcut" Return="check"
              Property="ElevatePowershellShortcut"
              Value="<WHAT-GOES-HERE?>" />
```

Where I've tried the following in place of `<WHAT-GOES-HERE?>`:

- [$PowershellShortcut] -- This almost gets me there. I get the folder the `.lnk` file is in, but not the file itself
- [$PowershellStartMenuShortcut] -- Empty string
- [#PowershellStartMenuShortcut] -- Empty string. This works on `<File>` elements...

An alternative would be to keep using the `[$PowershellShortcut]` value and also pass in the name of the `.lnk` file. Which would be the `<Shortcut>`'s `Name` attribute. I'm not sure how to get at it, either...

The reason I want to do this is that we've already had a case where the `Name` of the shortcut was changed, and everything stopped working, so we don't want to have to update the name/path of the shortcut in more than one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after I wrote this question, I came up with a solution. It's not quite what I asked for, but it solved my problem, so I'm posting it. If somebody can figure out how to do what I actually asked for, I will mark their answer as the correct one, although my solution is fairly clean and straight forward.

I ended up defining the following variable in my WiX define file:

```
<?define PowershellShortcutName="Powershell Environment" ?>
```

and then I set the `<Shortcut Name="$(var.PowershellShortcutName)">` and the `CustomAction` to:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionData_ElevatePowershellShortcut" Return="check"
              Property="ElevatePowershellShortcut"
              Value="[$PowershellShortcut]$(var.PowershellShortcutName).lnk" />
```

Everything works like it should now.